# tailwind css overflow hidden doesn't working in animation

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to animate an image by moving to different positions. but whenever it goes beyond the screen. the scrollbar appears. I tried adding overflow hidden in the parent element but it didn't worked. here is the required code snippet. I'm using tailwind css with nextjs

page.js

```
<main className="flex min-h-screen  items-center">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex">
        <div className="z-50 w-1/2">
          <h1 className="m-0 p-0 text-9xl">
            <span>{Title.slice(0, 2)}</span>
            <span className="text-secondary">{Title.slice(2)}</span>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className=" w-/2">
          <Image
            className="absolute z-10 animate-leftToRight"
            src={whiteCircle}
            alt="white circle"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#1c2340",
        secondary: "#f27eb2",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        Josefin: ["Josefin Sans", "sans-serif"],
        Poppins: ["Poppins", "sans-serif"],
      },
      animation: {
        leftToRight: "leftToRight 10s ease-in-out infinite",
      },
      keyframes: {
        leftToRight: {
          "0%, 100%": { left: "40%", top: "-20%", rotate: "0deg" },
          "50%": { left: "93%", top: "50%", rotate: "180deg" },
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

layout.js

```
<html lang="en">
      <body className="font-Poppins overflow-hidden max-w-[100vw] bg-primary text-white">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="mt-[60px]">{children}</div>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see in this image that white circle is at top and there isn't vertical scroll
[image: As you can see in this image that white circle is at top and there isn't vertical scroll]

now as soon as the image goes beyond the screen scroll appears

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `overflow-hidden` to the stacking context. At the moment that is the `html` element so you could add to globals.css:

```
html {
  @apply overflow-hidden;
}
```

Or you could create a new stacking context with `relative` and add the overflow hidden to that.

```
<main class="flex min-h-screen items-center relative overflow-hidden">
```

Exampe: https://play.tailwindcss.com/O8dHHydayG